# use ReactJS to .map through response of Express API

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express

I have an Express API that responds with data from MongoDB when requested upon mounting of a reactJS component.

```
app.get('/api/characters', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('usercollection');
  collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
    res.send({
      data: docs
    });
  });
});
```

Code for **Characters component** :

```
export default class Characters extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = CharactersStore.getState();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        CharactersStore.listen(this.onChange);
        CharactersActions.getCharacters('http://localhost:3000/api/characters');
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      CharactersStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
    }
    onChange(state) {
    this.setState(state);
  }
    render() {
        return (
            <section>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <h2 className="text-center">{this.props.route.header}</h2>
                <hr className="star-light"/>
                <CharacterList data={this.state.characters}/>
              </div>
            </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

Code for **Characters component**  Action

```
class CharactersActions {
  constructor() {
    this.generateActions(
      'getCharactersSuccess',
      'getCharactersFail'
    );
  }
  getCharacters(query) {
    requestPromise(query)
      .then((res) => {
        this.actions.getCharactersSuccess(res)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('error:', err);
        this.actions.getCharactersFail(err)
      })
  }
}

export default alt.createActions(CharactersActions);
```

Code for **Characters component**  Store

```
class CharactersStore {
  constructor() {
    this.bindActions(CharactersActions);
    this.characters = [''];
    this.isLoading = true;
  }
  getCharactersSuccess(res) {
    this.characters = res;
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
  getCharactersFail(err) {
    toastr.error(err.responseJSON && err.responseJSON.message || err.responseText || err.statusText);
  }
}

export default alt.createStore(CharactersStore);
```

The **Characters component** above requests the API upon mounting and sends the response data along to the store to be saved into State.

I then pass the Characters state into the child component **CharacterList** as props (named data)

**Characters List** Component

```
export default class CharacterList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    }

    render() {

        return (
        <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">

        {console.log(this.props.data)}

        // THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO .MAP THROUGH THE RESULTS

    </div>
        )
    }
}
```

***I am trying to use .map to loop through the returned data but am a little unsure on how to proceed, any advice would be appreciated. Data is being returned as follows:***

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "58d5044b0898f816066227f1",
      "character": "Luke Skywalker"
    },
    {
      "_id": "58d504c60898f816066227f2",
      "character": "Obi Wan Kenobi"
    },
    {
      "_id": "58d504c60898f816066227f3",
      "character": "Han Solo"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to set `res.data` as your `characters` store.

```js
getCharactersSuccess(res) {
  this.characters = res.data; // <--
  this.isLoading = false;
}
```

Then you can map over the `data` array, and not the full response:

```js
const data = [
  {
    _id: '58d5044b0898f816066227f1',
    character: 'Luke Skywalker'
  },
  {
    _id: '58d504c60898f816066227f2',
    character: 'Obi Wan Kenobi'
  },
  {
    _id: '58d504c60898f816066227f3',
    character: 'Han Solo'
  }
];

const Character = ({ data }) => <div>{data.character}</div>;

class CharacterList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map((character, i) => (
          <Character key={i} data={character} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CharacterList data={data} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I tried adding .data to my characters state before posting question, this seems to return NULL

Comment: Seems to return null? Could you check if it actually does?

Comment: Personally, I like to use the spread operator when mapping arrays like this, e.g. `<Character key={i} {...character} />`.  This way, you don't need an extra layer when using the values, e.g. `const Character = ({ character }) => <div>{character}</div>`.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper Good suggestion! But I can't be sure that OP is using the `babel-stage-3` preset, and if not the code would fail and result in further questions.

Comment: @FabianSchultz - confirmed it is returning as 'undefined'

Comment: @FabianSchultz Fair point... I've been using (and exploiting) it for so long I keep forgetting it isn't standard yet.

Comment: Is it undefined inside the store or the component?

Comment: both at store and in component level

Comment: Strange, could you add the full contents of `res` in the question?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.I dont know where you confused. try this

```
<div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">

{
    Array.isArray(this.props.data)&& this.props.data.map((val,index)=>{
          return val
        })
}
 </div>
```

Comment: hmm this is what I thought I needed, was  a bit confused by the initial 'data' array in my results. I have tried using your code but am getting this.props.data.map is not a function

Comment: This is  because, this.props.data is not defined on initial renderning.